# Add custom or any internet javascript to magento

Tags: magento

I am customizing magneto theme i was working on list.phtml file to show all products from specific categories on home page i did by including online jquery file at beginning of list.phtml file but home page sub categories are not showing on hover effect might me conflict with another js.. if i remove script from list.phtml file then sub categories are shown on hover effect but animation effect goes out. and if i remove script from list.phtml then sub categories shown on mouse hover effect but animation not.. i downloaded js file but don't know where to put this file in folder structure so my animation effect and hover effect both works fine.

[image]

Comment: Plz suggest solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include it in page.xml after prototype. Also you need to include jQuery.noConflict() to avoid conflicts of jquery and prototype

Comment: But where to put downloaded js in magento folder structure. and where to add jquery.noConflict...

Comment: You can add it in js folder. The line you need to include in page.xml is inside <reference name="head"> is : action method="addJs"><script>your_js_name.js</script></action>

Comment: Hey but my page.xml does not contain any reference name = "head" all are reference name = "root" tags are there.

Comment: Hey buddy, best way is to create a local.xml file in your layouts. Here I am attaching the code below as an answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>jquery.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>jquery-no-conflict.js</script></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
.
```